# How to truncate error message before get passed into tLogCatcher

Tags: error-handling, talend

I have a job that often failed originated from tRestClient (connecting to API)
This normally generates an error message which is quite long (longer than 255 character)
[image: job-Talend]

It seems to me the length of column in tLogCatcher schema is not modifiable.
[image: schema_tLogCatcher]

Is it possible to truncate the message to 255 before it enter the tLogCatcher ?

Answer (score 0):

You'd better truncate it AFTER it enters tLogCatcher, in tMap_5. For example with `StringHandling.LEFT(row3.message,255)`